# How to save the file in a path chosen by the user

Tags: c#

I am importing a source file and processing it and then after that I have to save it in a new location. I have created the syntax for importing file, tell me the syntax to save it to a new location. One is when I am calling the constructor to give the path of import file, then I can also give the path for the output location. But don't know how to implement it. Please tell.

Comment: more information would be helpful. What type of application, web or client?  Also will the user be clicking a save button or do you just want it to import and then save or will they be putting the save path in before uploading?

Comment: please specify whether the problem is with writing the file, or with allowing the user to choose the path, and what type of application you're working on (console, WinForms, asp, .. etc)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a SaveFileDialog pretty much like this:

```
using ( var dlg = new SaveFileDialog() )
{
    if ( dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        //SAVE THE OUTPUT
        //DEPENDING ON THE FORMAT, YOU MAY WANT TO USE
        //File.WriteAllBytes(dlg.FileName, yourBytes);
        //File.WriteAllText(dlg.FileName, yourText);
        //File.WriteAllLines(dlg.FileName, yourStringArr);
        //OR ANY OTHER CODE YOU WANT TO USE TO PERSIST YOUR DATA
    }
        //else the user clicked Cancel
}
```

Also, you can set a default extension, a default path and more. Look up [SaveFileDialog's information on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6sh4y16.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As your importing the file you could use the StreamWriter base class to write it to a file that the end user designates in a either a text box or a file upload box.